# Can I apply the variance inflation factor (VIF) for classified data?

Tags: python, pandas

All columns' values are class labels. For example: value "1" for feature1 is <50. Namely, all features were classified. In this case, can I apply the variance inflation factor (VIF) directly?

```
Dataset:
    feature1 feature2 feature3 target
        5       1         4      1
        1       1         3      0
        9       3         2      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with VIFs, as they are not always calculated in the way that you understand.
My suggestion is to calculate the VIF with numerical variables, in any case, you can make those variables dummies
This [article](https://statisticalhorizons.com/multicollinearity/) could give more explanation about: High VIFs are indicator (dummy) variables that represent a categorical variable with three or more categories

Comment: When I make them dummies, To get the VIF value for features if I calculate the average of VIFs of all classes of a feature, can it be true?